# How to create a Lookup field in Microsoft Access 2013 using SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

May I enquire as to how does one create a look-up field in a table in Microsoft Access 2013 (using the **CREATE TABLE** statement in SQL) which provides a drop-down box in Datasheet View that allows the user to select one or more entries in the field?

An example is as shown below (where the user can choose the fruit/(s) he/she likes from the drop down box in the **Fav_Fruit** field):

[image]

The values for the drop-down control are obtained from another table called **Fruits** (stored within the same Access database) shown below:

[image]

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shiraz,

These are properties you will need to create in VBA code. Is this an option for you?

```
Function AddLookupField()


    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim prp As DAO.Property
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set tdf = db.TableDefs("MyTable")

    Set fld = tdf.CreateField("Fav_Fruit", dbText)
    tdf.Fields.Append fld

    Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("DisplayControl", dbInteger, AcControlType.acComboBox)
    fld.Properties.Append prp

    Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("RowSourceType", dbText, "Value List")
    fld.Properties.Append prp

    Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("RowSource", dbText, "Orange; Pear; Apple")
    fld.Properties.Append prp


End Function
```

This example uses a value list (string of values). If you want the values to come from another table/query, experiment with these properties:

```
Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("RowSourceType", dbText, "Table/Query")
fld.Properties.Append prpProperty
Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("RowSource", dbText, "SELECT ID FROM SomeOtherTable")
fld.Properties.Append prpProperty
```

Comment: Hi Daniel,Oh dear, I was really hoping to be able to do this within SQL itself, rather than using VBA ... :(

Comment: I honestly don't know of a way to do this with SQL only. This is more of an Access feature that helps in datasheet or table view, and not necessarily a DAO or ADO feature (JET DB engine). This is why it is handled through VBA, or behind the scenes through VBA when you are in table design mode within Access. If I understood your situation a little more I could probably help. Depending on where you are firing the SQL to create the table, there is likely a way to call VBA as well (from within Access, from an external app, etc.).